# Copying List in Setter makes XML Unmarshaller not work

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a DataBean like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DataBean {
    private List<String> data;

    @XmlElement(name = "data")
    public List<String> getData() {
        return data != null ? Collections.unmodifiableList(data) : null;
    }

    public void setData(List<String> data) {
        data = new ArrayList<>(data);
        data.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Inside of the DataBean, the list must be sorted, otherwise the DataBean is not usable in my domain. In order to avoid side effects, I copy the list in the setter and then sort it.

Marshalling this bean works fine, but when unmarshalling, the data list is empty (not null). Here is some code to demonstrate:

```
public class XmlTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> data = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four");
        DataBean dataBean = new DataBean();
        dataBean.setData(data);
        System.out.printf("Data in original bean: %s%n%n", dataBean.getData().toString());

        try {
            String xmlString = serialize(dataBean);
            System.out.printf("XML:%n%s%n", xmlString);
            DataBean deserializedDataBean = deserialize(xmlString);
            System.out.printf("Data in deserialized bean: %s%n%n", deserializedDataBean.getData().toString());
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String serialize(DataBean dataBean) throws JAXBException {
        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataBean.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(dataBean, w);
        return w.toString();
    }

    private static DataBean deserialize(String xmlString) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataBean.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        return (DataBean) um.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlString));
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Data in original bean: [four, one, three, two]

XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dataBean>
    <data>four</data>
    <data>one</data>
    <data>three</data>
    <data>two</data>
</dataBean>

Data in deserialized bean: []
```

If I remove the line `data = new ArrayList<>(data);` from the setter in the bean, unmarshalling works like a charm, so the copy operation seems to be the problem.

**Why does copying make the list in the deserialized bean empty, and can I fix this without removing the copy operation?**

Of course I could instead test if the data is sorted and throw an IllegalArgumentException if it isn't, but I would prefer to sort a copy in the setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class DataBean {


    @XmlElement(name = "data")
    private List<String> data;

    public List<String> getData() {
        return data != null ? Collections.unmodifiableList(data) : null;
    }

    public void setData(List<String> data) {
        data = new ArrayList<>(data);
        data.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

```
Data in original bean: [four, one, three, two]

XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dataBean>
    <data>four</data>
    <data>one</data>
    <data>three</data>
    <data>two</data>
</dataBean>

Data in deserialized bean: [four, one, three, two]
```

Comment: Yes, this solves it, thanks! I guess if you set it like this, the unmarshaller does not use the setter, but instead makes the private field accessible and sets it via reflection? I still don't understand why it did not work before though, could you explain that? :)

Comment: In this way, the access fields are still accessed through the setter and getter. I guess XmlElement ignores setters when decorating methods. Although XmlElement can decorate a method, the comments for XmlElement do not explain the behavior when you decorate a method.

Comment: I did try it out and debugged it, the setter is not used in your version.

Comment: Both the setter and getter are used when I debug.